# Get table content, convert JS into jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to provide the following code as jQuery function. I dont know how the loop should be:

JS

```
 var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

jQuery

```
 var table = $('#mytable');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function(_, row) {
    $('td', row).each(function(_, cell) {
        alert( $(cell).html() );
    });
});
```

Comment: The first argument in `.each(index, element)` is the index, and that's not needed here, so I just used an underscore instead, makes no difference